# how to import json data using aerospike query language?

Tags: json, database, import, aerospike, aql

```
http://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/
```

I am new to aerospike. I have read the basic documentation on aql but stuck on importing data. I have a json data and i have to import it in aerospike using aql. Is there any command for importing the data in aerospike?

Comment: What have you found so far about you're trying to achieve? Have you written some code? Please show in your question what you already have tried. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aerospike does offer a csv loader

Please see:

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-loader

Comment: hello Colibri, I am having problem in importing nested csv file using aerospike loader.Can you please help?  I have uploaded the details in the following link:                                                                                                                      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32794867/how-to-load-a-nested-csv-file-in-aerospike-using-aerospike-loader